# retrieving maxResult in worklogs using jira JQL issue

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql, jqlite

I have a simple jql query that gives me all the issues and work logs. The worklogs however seem to cap at 20. How can I force it to retrieve all ? E.g

http://website/rest/api/2/search?jql=project in (Project) and issueFunction in workLogged("after 2015/10/12 before 2015/10/17") &startAt=0&maxResults=1000&fields=worklog

How can I force that the max results for work log is for example 100 instead of 20. I am unable to find any references on how to change the max when it is inner node.

Comment: 20 seems oddly low, are you sure the query should return more results than that? Have you tried changing to a simple query to make sure you ever get more than 20 results?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you cannot force Jira to return all worklogs. The 20 cap is a known issue at Atlassian and awaits fixing. News can be found at the bug ticket: 
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-34746

There are possibilities to use SQL to query your Jira database for the worklog data:

1. Directly, which can be considered deprecated because of the risks:

> "Zero security ... could potentially slow the Jira system access ... inefficient queries"

2. Via a third-party plugin

> " 'SQL for JIRA', a new plugin for JIRA which supports standard SQL against the JIRA API"

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/17373/can-i-acess-the-jira-database-to-run-my-own-querys

I can't guarantee that either works for you but it is a starting point until the bug is fixed.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could get all the worklogs separately without any **maxResult** limits using the following link:

```
 ../rest/api/2/issue/your_issue_id/worklog/
```